# How to make an increment function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, increment

I am trying to make a function in which you take in a value and it returns the value increased by 1.

For example,

```
int n=5;
printf("%d \n", n);
increment(n);
printf("%d \n", n);
```

should give an OUTPUT of:

```
5     
6
```

Changing the value by using n++ or n+=1 inside the increment function is not changing the global variable.
I do realise that pointers can be used to solve this problem, but I am unable to figure out how.
Please help me out.

Comment: You are asking for `int increment(int x) { return x + 1; }` which is a "a function in which you take in a value and it returns the value increased by 1".  Rest of post sounds like you want something else. Sounds like you want `increment()` to receive a pointer to an `int` and then you want the function to increment that `int`.  No return values are involved.  Please post your code that "Changing the value by using n++ or n+=1 inside the increment function is not changing the global variable."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use return value simply pass the pointer to your variable

```
void increment(int *x)
{
    *x += 1;
}
int main() 
{
    int n=5;
    printf("%d \n", n);
    increment(&n);
    printf("%d \n", n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the result that value **n** changed, you can do it without using pointers

```
int n = 5;
printf("%d \n", n);
n = increment(n);
printf("%d \n", n);
```

And your increment function must return value with type **int**